# Removal of Duplicated Records Using Nested Select

Tags: mysql

from the following table,

[image]

how will below output should be queried?

[image]

My initial query is:

```
select
    bpai.sequence_id, bpai.last_name, bpai.given_name,
    bpai.middle_name, bpai.middle_initial,
    bpai.gender, bpai.birth_date, bpai.birth_place_via_psgc, bpai.citizenship,
    bpai.primary_mobile_number, bpai.primary_email_address, count(*)
    from bpaitbl bpai
    inner join (select 
                    *, count(*) as countof
                    from bpaitbl
                    group by
                        last_name, middle_name,
                        gender, birth_date, citizenship
                    having (count(*) > 1)
     ) profil on bpai.last_name like profil.middle_name 
        and bpai.gender = profil.gender
        and bpai.birth_date = profil.birth_date
        and bpai.citizenship = profil.citizenship        
;
```

and can't make the output anyhow i tried. please help.

Comment: Please post code as text in a code block. Not as image. Also explain the logic of the expected result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: done

Comment: Why sawi-robert and sawi-josie was removed since they aren't duplicated?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say in your question, but mention in your title, what the result set represents, I presume you want a list of rows with duplicate records.

The following query will list all of the records with duplicate records, showing the record with the highest sequence_id of the duplicates:

```
SELECT
    a.sequence_id,
    a.last_name,
    a.given_name,
    a.middle_name,
    a.gender,
    a.birth_date,
    a.citizenship
FROM bpaitbl a
LEFT JOIN bpaitbl b
ON a.last_name = b.last_name AND
    a.given_name = b.given_name AND
    a.middle_name = b.middle_name AND
    a.gender = b.gender AND
    a.birth_date = b.birth_date AND
    a.citizenship = b.citizenship AND
    a.sequence_id > MAX(b.sequence_id)
WHERE b.sequence_id IS NULL;
GROUP BY 
    a.last_name,
    a.given_name,
    a.middle_name,
    a.gender,
    a.birth_date,
    a.citizenship
```

To show the record with the lowest sequence_id, change the `>` to `<`. If you want all rows, including those without duplicates, remove the where clause.